# Discord bot role command stopped working for unknown reasons

Tags: discord.js

I have a command which worked, but at some point stopped, returning to the chat message that the role does not exist. An error "(node:12228) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead" is sent to the console every time I use a command, but I always had it

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MEMBERS")) return message.reply();
  let rMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
  if(!rMember) return message.reply("nope.");
  let role = args.join(" ").slice(22);
  if(!role) return message.reply("nope!");
  let gRole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, role);
  if(!gRole) return message.reply("role does not exist.");
  const allowed = ['some id'];

  if (!allowed.includes(gRole.id)) return;
  if(rMember.roles.has(gRole.id)) return message.reply("nope.");
  await(rMember.removeRoles(['some id']));
  await(rMember.addRole(gRole.id));
  if(gRole.id == 'id') rMember.addRole('id') && rMember.removeRoles(['some id']);;

  try{
    await rMember.send(`you got ${gRole.name}!`)
  }catch(e){
  }
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "role"
}
```

So I need the command to work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194931/discussion-on-question-by-maevo-discord-bot-role-command-stopped-working-for-unk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order of appearance, I see these mistakes in your code...

- You're not catching any rejected promises.
- `MANAGE_MEMBERS` is not a valid [permission flag](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS).
- You should pass a function into [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find).
- No idea what you're trying to do with the declaration of `role`.
- Your use of the `&&` [logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) in your `if` statement is incorrect. Use a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) instead.
- Your `catch` block in the [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement has been left empty.

Combining the answers provided to your other questions about this code, this is a correct, much cleaner rewrite...

```js
const getMention = require('discord-mentions'); // Don't forget to install.

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  if (!message.guild) return;

  try {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return;

    if (!args[1]) return await message.reply('Please provide a user.');
    if (!args[2]) return await message.reply('Please provide a role.');
    if (args[3]) return await message.reply('Too many arguments provided.');

    let member;
    if (getMention(args[1])) member = getMention(args[1], message.guild).member;
    else member = message.guild.members.find(m => m.user.tag === args[1] || m.id === args[1]);

    if (!member) return await message.reply('Invalid user provided.');

    let role;
    if (getMention(args[2])) role = getMention(args[2], message.guild).role;
    else role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === args[2] || r.id === args[2]);

    if (!role) return await message.reply('Invalid role provided.');

    const allowed = ['role1ID', 'role2ID', 'role3ID'];
    if (!allowed.includes(role.id)) return await message.reply('That role is not allowed.');

    if (member.roles.has(role.id)) return await message.reply('That user already has that role.');

    await member.removeRoles(['someID', 'someOtherID']);
    await member.addRole(role.id);

    if (role.id === 'anAlternateRoleID') {
      await member.removeRoles(['someID', 'someOtherID']);
      await member.addRole('otherRoleID');
    }

    await member.send(`You got the ${role.name} role.`)
      .catch(() => console.log(`Couldn't send message to ${member.user.tag}.`));
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

module.exports.help = {
  name: 'role'
};
```

Keep in mind, if you're removing just one role from a member, you should use the singular version of the method, [`GuildMember.removeRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=removeRole).

Comment: I trying to use !role @User#0000 Testrole, but I get message "Please provide a role."

Comment: Check your `args` array. You may have shifted it so that the first argument is `args[0]`. In that case, subtract one from all the `args` indexes in the code.

Comment: Rang is second argument

Comment: Second in the array? If so, change `args[1]` in the code to `args[0]`, and `args[2]` to `args[1]`.